# Magento2 Add Custom Field On Checkout Billing Address With Validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

i have created custom field on checkout billing address and it is showing perfect and i also add required field valdation but it is not working.

someone help me with this please.

> i have add below code using layout processor

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']['children']['customfield'] = [
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config' => [
                            'customScope' => 'billingAddress',
                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                            'id' => 'customfield'
                        ],
                        'dataScope' => $groupConfig['dataScopePrefix'].'.customfield',
                        'label' => __('Custom'),
                        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'visible' => true,
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
                        'sortOrder' => 75,
                        'id' => 'custom-field',
                      
                    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer following [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) from dev docs

Use billingAddress instead shippingAddress and use 'billing-step' instead of 'shipping-step'
Hopefully it will work .

Thanks